# I want to create a ROS package? how can i?

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to create two nodes on ROS, and want them to communicate and analyze the robot's local and global reference frames. To be precise i want to examine the position of the robot in x, y and theta coordinates, then send this result to another node which will convert it to global reference frame and then send it to another node. please help me with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227941/i-want-to-create-a-ros-package?-how-can-i?/) by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) will teach you how to create ROS nodes and packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2